# APP_INITIALIZER blank page

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular12, ngrx-store-4.0

I got a problem using APP_INITIALIZER. Everything seems to work fine, function hits endpoint and returs and executes resolve(true). The problem is that after all I can see only blank screen. 0 errors in console. Here is the code:

```
    export function initApplication(store: Store<fromRoot.State>){//() => Observable<any> {
return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
  store.dispatch(AppActions.StartAppInitializer());
  store.dispatch(AppActions.LoadUserSettings());
  store.select(fromRoot.getUserSettingsLoaded)
  .pipe(
    tap(userSettingsLoaded => console.log(userSettingsLoaded)),
    filter(userSettingsLoaded =>  userSettingsLoaded == true),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe((userSettingsLoaded) => {
    store.dispatch(AppActions.FinishAppInitializer());
    resolve(true);
  })})}
}
```

Here code in @NgModule in app.module.ts in providers section

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
  useFactory: initApplication,
  multi: true,
  deps: [Store]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do a console.log in your subscribe what do you see? Also what are you supposed to see after the app is initiated?

Comment: https://mohy-eid.medium.com/initialize-angular-app-with-ngrx-app-initializer-6556b819e0e3

Did you add the store module to the app.module.ts ?

Comment: @Tommi I see ,,true". I want to see home page, now with this problem <router-outlet> is just empty.

Comment: @StéphaneM Yes i have. If I change filter condition to true == true then everything works fine, app loads.

Comment: do you see user settings being loaded in the network tab?

Comment: edited code a little because posted wrong code on begging but still same effect - blank page. Yes i see user settings loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out the problem were guards firing at same time as APP_INITIALIZER. They were not waiting for app_init to finish and they needed result of action from app_init. That's why page wasn't appearing - guards were blocking them. For me the solution was to add in app.routing.module.ts

```
initialNavigation: 'disabled'
```

and then enabling it in constructor of app.component.ts

```
   router.initialNavigation();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like it is the filter condition that isnt evaluated correctly. Im wondering if your select is the reason it's not working, can you try and remove the pipe() surrounding the select?

Change this:

```
store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getUserSettingsLoaded))
```

to this:

```
select(fromRoot.getUserSettingsLoaded)
```

Comment: Edited code a little, by mistake posted not best verion on begging. Still same effect - blank page. Tried  your suggestion but doesn't help. Console.log in tap logs "true" and then function gets resolved.

Comment: A real head scratcher! What type of value does the getUserSettings hold? Is it also a boolean and not a string with "true" ? Cause that would make the filter eval become false.